# Visual Studio Diagramming Dependencies

Tags: visual-studio, uml, diagram

I would like my dependencies (association, inheritance, etc) represented as non-orthogonal lines.  How do I turn off the ortho-snap that is provided by default?

Also, MS says it is possible visually to [convert associations into properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8tkebx17%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).  More specifically, they call it "hiding association and inheritance lines."  Unfortunately, the context menu option "Hide" does not exist, despite the claim of the documentation.

Must I have the "visualization and modelling feature pack 2" to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The convert associations into properties is only available with the Class Diagram (*.cd extension) that has been in VS since 2005.  The new UML Class Diagram (*.classdiagram extension) that is part of the VS2010 Ultimate does not provide this feature.

As for non-orthogonal lines (aka straight lines) you cannot do this in VS Class Diagram (aka Class Designer) nor can you do in in VS2010 UML Class Diagrams.

Both of these would be a good features to request for the Feature Pack 3 or SP1.